# angular-strap modal transitions

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm trying to use Angular-Strap to handle modal opening/closing from the controller. However the backdrop animation CSS given on the Angular-Strap docs keeps giving me errors - pretty sure I'm using it wrong, but I can't seem to find much info on how to use the CSS. [Here's a plunker of the problem.](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4cAG8IZSN1doZUeAqd4?p=preview) It seems like it's the ampersands causing problems. Here is the code given on the angular-strap docs:

```
.modal-backdrop.am-fade {
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
    &.ng-enter {
        opacity: 0;
        &.ng-enter-active {
            opacity: .5;
        }
    }
    &.ng-leave {
        opacity: .5;
        &.ng-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: To further clarify, opening/closing the modals doesn't cause me problems. The CSS actually does seem to work until it gets to the &.ng-enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed CSS to look like so:

```
.modal-backdrop.am-fade {
    opacity: .7;
    transition: opacity .35s linear;
}
.modal-backdrop.am-fade.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop.am-fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: .5;
}

.modal-backdrop.am-fade.ng-leave {
    opacity: .5;
}
.modal-backdrop.am-fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I was having the same problem with the collapse animation.  I don't know why I didn't realize the sample code in the AngularStrap docs was LESS and not CSS.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see you've effectively figured out the problem, but for completeness' sake: the syntax with the ampersands is using LESS CSS style syntax.

As you assumed, the ampersand is used as the parent element, so in this case, '&' gets preprocessed to become '.modal-backdrop' because it is used within the braces of the .modal-backdrop's CSS.

LESS adds a layer of syntactic sugar on top of CSS, but requires a pre-processor to do a pass over the LESS to convert it all to standard CSS, which is why it wouldn't have worked for you until you manually did the preprocessing.

See: http://lesscss.org/

(Note:  I'd add this as a comment instead of an answer, but I can't yet comment on posts because I don't have enough internet points.)

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying! Thought it was weird that the docs would use this formatting, since I assumed it was faulty when it didn't work for me..now I know :)